# Ordenação de dados de uma coluna para outra

Tags: mysql, classificação

Estou montando uma hierarquia e tudo esta funcionando corretamente, só tenho um pequeno problema, na ordenação dos dados.

Segue a estrutura da tabela. (o mais básico possível)

```
create table hierarquia (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hierarquia_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

e os dados são esses:

```
insert into hierarquia values
(1, 0), 
(2, 0), 
(3, 1), 
(4, 1),
(5, 0),
(6, 3);
```

Quando faço minha query `select * from hierarquia order by hierarquia_id, id` não retorna os dados na ordem que preciso.

```
ID | HIERARQUIA_ID
1  | 0
2  | 0 
5  | 0
3  | 1 
4  | 1
6  | 3
```

Precisaria que retornasse os dados mais coerentemente ordenados por suas hierarquias, sendo que teria que retornar os dados assim:

```
ID | HIERARQUIA_ID
1  | 0
3  | 1 
6  | 3
4  | 1
2  | 0 
5  | 0
```

Primeiro a primeira hierarquia sem sub hierarquia, as próximas sendo as sub-hierarquia da primeira e consecutivamente.

Existe essa possibilidade no [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) ?

**[Exemplo no SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91b6ba/3)**

Comment: Putz cara, bancos de dados relacionais não são bons com estruturas em árvore como essa sua. Você quer retornar a lista dos nós da árvore quando percorrida em pré-ordem. O MySQL é bem espartano para lidar com dados espaciais.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos o banco em si roda bem, o meu único problema mesmo esta sendo nessa ordenação. Eu até entendo o que quer dizer, mas estou tentando, pois infelizmente não tenho como mudar essa estrutura, muito mesmo para um noSql, pelo menos não agora. Mas valew pelo retorno.

Comment: Então não existe uma forma direta de fazer isso. A melhor forma de fazer será usando a linguagem de programação na aplicação que acessa esses dados.

Comment: Existem algumas "adequações técnicas", que você encontra [aqui](http://web.archive.org/web/20110606032941/http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/hierarchical-data.html) e que podem dar uma luz para você resolver seu problema.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada, e como disse, pode ser que eu faça na programação mesmo. Valew

Answer (score 2):

### Solução usando stored procedure

Achei no SOEN, uma solução baseada em stored procedure, o que não requer alteração da estrutura do banco:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035966/195417

### Solução alterando a estrutura do banco

Já trabalhei uma vez com esse problema de ordenar os registros na mesma ordem em que aparecem na árvore, e a solução final, foi criar uma nova coluna no banco de dados, com o endereço da cada registro dentro da árvore, em forma de string mesmo:

```
ID | HIERARQUIA_ID | ENDERECO
1  | 0             | "1"
2  | 0             | "2"
3  | 1             | "1\3"
4  | 1             | "1\4"
5  | 0             | "5"
6  | 3             | "1\3\6"
```

Depois de ordenar pela coluna endereço, ficaria no ordem que você quer:

```
ID | HIERARQUIA_ID | ENDERECO
1  | 0             | "1"
3  | 1             | "1\3"
6  | 3             | "1\3\6"
4  | 1             | "1\4"
2  | 0             | "2"
5  | 0             | "5"
```

### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3d4cd/1)

Comment: Não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade, entendi e achei bacana, mas para isso preciso alterar minha estrutura e também irei ter que trabalhar no programação que salva esses dados na base (algo que para isso no momento não vou ter tempo) mas fica a dica relatada aqui.

Comment: A construção do endereço e mesmo da lista de adjacência ordenada pode ser feita via *stored procedures*; apesar de concordar com o Henrique que isso fica melhor e mais performático na camada de aplicação. Veja essa pergunta na [DBA Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes). O valor do endereço pode ser calculado com uma função análoga a `GetAncestry` que concatena os nós em pré-ordem.

Comment: [Prova de conceito](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11b4f3/3) usando sugestão do Miguel + adaptação da função mencionada (não requer uma nova coluna no banco). Funciona, porém essas concatenações e o fato de cada parente de um nó significar um `SELECT` torna essa solução bem problemática em termos de *performance*.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly: essa resposta do DBA Exchange conicidentemente é a mesma que eu achei, mas linkado de dentro de uma resposta no SOEN. =D

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly: em falar nisso, a sua prova de conceito ficou ótima. Valeu! O único problema seria mesmo a performance.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz: Cara, agora não é mais uma questão de tempo... você pode simplesmente criar a coluna `ENDERECO` e então usar a stored procedure num `UPDATE` pra atualizar todo o banco com os valores corretos. Assim, você tem performance, e ao mesmo tempo resolve o problema rápido... a não ser que haja outras questões envolvidas.

Comment: Viva o [RolandoMySQLDBA](http://stackexchange.com/users/229057/rolandomysqldba) que propôs (e replicou a solução). Se quiser copiar ou adaptar a POC e incluir na resposta fique a vontade :).

Comment: Galera, muito bom mesmo, agradeço a todos e vou analisar o que melhor fazer. @AnthonyAccioly sua prova de conceito ficou boa mesmo, mas tem a questão da performance que pode prejudicar. Agradeço a todos mesmo.

Comment: Marcelo, conforme sugestão do Miguel você pode criar uma coluna endereço (devidamente indexada) e usar minha `function` para alimentá-la (um `update` inicial na tabela toda e talvez uns *triggers* espertos `on insert` e `on update` que propaguem modificações árvore abaixo). Essa é uma solução mais performática (trocando cálculos a cada leitura por cálculos pré-indexados durante operações de escrita). Melhor do que isso só trazendo o problema para uma linguagem de programação capaz de lidar com grafos / estruturas de dados hierárquicas mesmo.